# Need I use NodeJS to show an OpenLayers 3 map inside a page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers-3

I am absolutly new in **OpenLayers 3** and I have started studying this tutorial: http://openlayers.org/workshop/index.html

As you can see in the previous link is specified that:

> In addition, you'll need Node installed to run a development server
>   for the OpenLayers library.

So it means that for evry application that show a map using Open Layers 3 I need to install also **Node JS**? Why to show a map I need Node?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenLayers is a javascript client library.
No server-side is required to run it.

They use node js to make builds and so on, but it is not mandatory at all!

You can just use the full builds that you can download from the openlayers website and write your html/js code without any additional tool.

Comment: Ok, tnx. What do you exactly means when you say: "to make builds and so on"?

Comment: You can create "custom builds" with just the components you need http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html

Comment: Or you can compile OL together with your app http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/doc/tutorials/closure.html